# Javascript memory leak with Vue JS and Velocity JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, velocity.js

I have been working with Velocity.js and Vue.js and ran into a memory leak. Fiddle of the issue: You can see an example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hRAn7/3/

```
$(function () {

    var ExtVue = Vue.extend({
        'template': '#template',
        'replace': true
    });

    var currVue;

    setInterval(function () {
        var nextVue = new ExtVue();
        nextVue.$appendTo($('body').get(0));

        $(nextVue.$el).velocity({
            'left': '0'
        }, 0, callback);

        function callback() {
            if (currVue)
                currVue.$destroy();
            currVue = nextVue;
        }

    }, 10);
});
```

I used Chrome's timeline function and noticed that the number of DOM nodes never decreases, even when I force a garbage collection. I started diving into the heap profiler but it is a bit over my head.

When I us `.animate()` instead of `.velocity()`, the DOM nodes seem to get GCed correctly.

```
$(nextVue.$el).animate({
    'left': '0'
}, 0, callback);
```

It also seems that removing Vue also fixes the problem. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yV6Zr/1/.

What could be causing this memory leak?

Comment: It will be very hard to investigate source of memory leaks with minified library

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to include an unminified version of velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved on velocity.js GitHub page:

https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/300